# Cross-fade between two images on page load then stop

Tags: fade

Once the page has finished loading, I would like one image to cross-fade to another. Not in a loop, just once.

The effect I would like to create can be seen here:

[Blur Fade](http://www.garethwebb.co.uk/)

I am sure it must be quite simple using jQuery?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Quite right, I thought I might apply a blur in Photoshop to an image and then fade from the in focus image to the blurred image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can crossfade between two images by positioning them in the same place using CSS, then calling `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` using jQuery.

For example:

```
$(function() {
    $('img.OldImage').fadeOut();
    $('img.NewImage').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: @Anthony: Yes, but it won't be any different.

Comment: To expand on my comment above, could I use fadeTo() as I am only using two images?
Have the two images absolutely positioned one on top of the other using CSS and fade the top image to opacity 0?


    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('img.TopImage').delay(500).fadeTo('normal',0);

    });

Is this correct? Would this apply to the image with the class .TopImage applied to it?

Comment: Yes, but that's equaivalent to `fadeIn()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
        $('.byeIMG').fadeOut("slow");
        $('.heyIMG').fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```